# There is uniswap error I can't able to reasole it

Tags: node-modules, uniswap

I am using Uniswap SDK for swapping the tokens I was working fine but now it is throwing an error, but I don't know why. I also install npm **@uniswap/v3-periphery** but it can't work for me.

**Here is the error:**

```
./node_modules/@uniswap/v3-sdk/dist/v3-sdk.esm.js:7:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IMulticall.sol/IMulticall.json'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@uniswap/smart-order-router/build/module/providers/on-chain-quote-provider.js
./node_modules/@uniswap/smart-order-router/build/module/providers/index.js
./node_modules/@uniswap/smart-order-router/build/module/index.js
./components/app/Swapping.jsx
./pages/swap/index.tsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

And here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "helpi-finance",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.0",
    "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit": "^0.5.1",
    "@uniswap/sdk": "^3.0.3",
    "@uniswap/sdk-core": "^3.0.1",
    "@uniswap/smart-order-router": "^2.5.30",
    "@uniswap/v3-sdk": "^3.8.2",
    "ethers": "^5.0.0",
    "jsbi": "3.2.5",
    "next": "^12.1.6",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.4",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.8",
    "wagmi": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.35",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.9",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.1.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After Stuck **3 to 4 Days** If find out, By installing a specific version of **@uniswap/v3-periphery@1.4.1** resolves this issue.

```
npm i @uniswap/v3-periphery@1.4.1
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with js so don't add the js snippet comment. Don't do that. Just press Ctrl+K to format as code or use triple backticks

Answer (score 0):

```
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Ethjs/uniswapV3_SDK/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269
        const error: any = new Error(message);
                           ^
Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.1)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/xxx/Desktop/Ethjs/uniswapV3_SDK/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/xxx/Desktop/Ethjs/uniswapV3_SDK/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/Desktop/Ethjs/uniswapV3_SDK/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:483:23)
    at step (/Users/xxx/Desktop/Ethjs/uniswapV3_SDK/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (/Users/xxx/Desktop/Ethjs/uniswapV3_SDK/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (/Users/xxx/Desktop/Ethjs/uniswapV3_SDK/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  reason: 'could not detect network',
  code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',
  event: 'noNetwork'
}
```

After I run follow your instruction, I got this problem instead? Do you counter the same problem?

Comment: I'm stupid. I forgot to import "dotenv" lol